# .NET implementation of the active object pattern

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, design-patterns, asynchronous

I'm looking for implementations of the active object pattern, but haven't for much so far. This is what I came up with:

- http://geekswithblogs.net/dbose/archive/2009/10/17/c-activeobject-runnable.aspx

Need something a little bit more involved. Preferably for .NET Version <= 3.5.

Comment: I assume you saw this link from that page? http://blog.gurock.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/01/activeobjects.pdf

Comment: The bachelor thesis is very interesting but it doesn't contain an implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`System.Threading.Tasks.Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx).

Comment: Ok, that's a good one. Too bad my project is using .NET 3.5 :(

Answer (score 3):

The simple implementation that uses System.Threading.Tasks.Task

```
class ActiveObject : IDisposable
{
    private Task _lastTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { });

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_lastTask == null)
            return;

        _lastTask.Wait();
        _lastTask = null;
    }

    public void InvokeAsync(Action action)
    {
        if (_lastTask == null)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(GetType().FullName);

        _lastTask = _lastTask.ContinueWith(t => action());
    }
}
```

`InvokeAsync` isn't thread-safe, use `lock (_lastTask) lastTask = ...;` if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at the code, but this seems to be an implementation of the active object pattern.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/LongRunningActiveObject.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Anton Tykhyy's answer, there is a version of System.Threading.Tasks.Task for .NET 3.5 available as a part of [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/gg577610). Note that this version does not have official support from Microsoft.